# 3440x1440 Ultrawide desktop rendering

Tags: 20.04, xorg, thinkpad, xrandr

For starters I'm running 20.04, up to date 100%.

I have an Asus 34" ultrawide that runs native 3440x1440@100 in DP and 3440x1440@50 in HDMI.

My laptop is a 14" Thinkpad with a Ryzen PRO 2700U and integrated Vega 10 graphics. I have my Laptop docked in a standard Thinkpad desktop dock (the type that it locks in for offices etc...)

I'm trying to connect to my monitor via HDMI. It is 100% not the cable or any hardware related issue, you'll see why. The problem scenarios are as follows (laptop is docked for all of them):

1. Connect to monitor, hotkey for monitor only, screen tears.
2. Connect to monitor, hotkey for laptop and monitor display, screen tears.
3. Trying both of the above and using CtlAltDel to log out, screen is fine at login display until I login again, then screen tears.
4. Connect to monitor, hotkey for monitor only, screen tears, use tab/ent/spc to navigate to the advanced button in the hotkey popup, use the same keys to set the resolution to 1920x1080@60, the screen is fine (at 1080).
5. Use xrandr in terminal and "test" suggestions that there are 10-E65 results for in google when in 1080. Trying every 3440x1440 refresh rate conceivable yields the same result, screen tears.

Here's where everything got flipped upside down, literally.

6. If I plug my monitor in, TAB my life away to get it to 1920x1080@60 in the display settings menu, set it to 3440x1440@50, set the rotation to inverted and set the reflection to horizontal and vertical (making it not inverted anymore, technically) IT RENDERS FINE. Desktop is usable, full 3440x1440@50. I'm at a loss...

[Picture of tearing referenced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52XLx.jpg)

Any help or education on this mess is much appreciated.